# Convert XML to ResourceDictionary

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt

New to XSLT, so I'm probably doing something stupid.

I have a bunch of XML documents that I am needing to convert to WPF Resource Dictionaries.  (Changing the way string resources are handled.)

The nodes are converting fine, but I am having an issue with the namespace declarations being outputted to the child elements, when they should be on the ResourceDictionary element.

Sample XML:

```
<root>
  <data name="StringName" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>String Value</value>
    <comment>String Description</comment>
  </data>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     
                              xmlns:loc="Localization"
                              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                            >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="ResourceDictionary" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/data" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:element name="loc:Text" >
            <xsl:attribute name="x:Key">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Content">
                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="TranslComment">
                <xsl:value-of select="comment" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="FormatComment">
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <loc:Text xmlns:loc="Localization" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Key="StringName" Content="String Value" TranslComment="String Description" FormatComment=""/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I've tried putting the namespace declarations everywhere, using namespace attributes and xsl:attribute nodes.  I get the same results each time.

What am I missing?  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the namespace declarations on the root element, try declaring them on the root element in the XSLT

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:loc="Localization">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="root/data" />
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

(Note, there is no need to use `xsl:element` to create an element if it is a static name)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     
                              xmlns:loc="Localization"
                              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:loc="Localization">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/data" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <loc:Text x:Key="{@name}" Content="{value}" TranslComment="{comment}" FormatComment="" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to create the attributes on the `loc:Text` element.

Comment: That looks like it did it.  Thank you very much.